# Ubuntu server behind 2 routers dns problem

Tags: domain-name-system, router, routing, linux

I come from stackoverflow and I am looking for a sysadmin guru who can solve my problem.

I have a 2 router + "server" configuration. the first router (router A) has ip range 192.168.2.1 - 254
the "second" (router B) one 192.168.3.1 - 254 and has a fixed ip from the one within the 2 range.

behind router B is a computer who serves as a server. It leases a static ip adress from router B.

I configured the routers that external acces is touted to the server and internal aswell.

So far so good.

now the tricky part for me. I can acces the server from outside the network with a domain name:

name.something.org. -> this works

now I have a webapplication that routes me to name.something.org, when I access it. This works fine from outside the network, but not from inside the network.

My computer is connected to router B (same as server) my servername is: name, and Router B's domain name is something. org.

Both my server and my computer are on domain something.org. but when i do a ping, I am still rerouted to router A which gives me problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this.

It would be very appriciated :)

(thank you for reading this for and trying to understand what I am trying to explain with)

@ edit: when i check my ip settings on both computer and server I can see that the dns suffix is something.org:

```
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : something.org
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.252
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.1
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/167601/no-ip-works-for-non-internal-clients-pinging-works-internally/167607#167607

Comment: that is what I do, I set the router domain to something.org, connect with computer and server on this domain. so normally when I do a request, the router sees it's on his domain, sees that one of the computers is name.something.org so it routes the request to that pc

Comment: I was thinking, because router B sends it's request to router A, can't I say that router A's domain name is org, router B's dn is something and my computer name is name, would router A receive the request, thinking it's for him because it's name is org then send it to somethin which reroutes it to the name ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just set a static route on router B to name.something.org (or its public IP) with gateway = internal IP of the server (192.168.3.???)

Comment: I will try that later and comment, I currently have no acces to my server and routers :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick (and perhaps dirty) way to probably solve this is to just edit the host file on your workstation to point to the IP of the server:

```
name.something.org     192.168.3.x
```

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Note: Serverfault has some problems with URLs containing patentheses, so cut and paste!

---

I guess the cause of the actual problem does not have anything to do with DNS names and domain name search orders, but rather that your router(s) will not DNAT/port forward traffic that arrives on an internal interface. Depending on the type of router you are using it might be an easy thing to fix, or it might be impossible to do. (I see now that this is also what is described in Zoredache's link posted earlier).